# Can I improve my validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

So I want to validate my form using jQuery, this is how I imagine it and it works, but is the best method of doing it and maybe I can do it more effective with less code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#frmCatAdd").submit(function()
        {
            var name = $("#edtName").val();

            if (name == "")
                $("#edtName").css("border", "1px solid red")
            else
                $("#frmCatAdd").submit();

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Make sure you duplicate your logic server-side.  Client-side validation (jQuery) is a user-convenience/performance optimization only.  The _real_ validation work must _always_ be server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [jValidate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in order to simplify and speed up your task. I use it as routinely as creating new forms.

However, I **strongly** recommend you validate on server side as well. All the user has to do is turn off Javascript to defeat your perfect validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is - do NOT only rely on javascript validation. You NEED to do server side validation as well!! This is extremely important. If I turn javascript off, I have bypassed your entire validation.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmCatAdd").submit(function() {
        var $edtname = $("#edtName"),
            name     = $edtname.val();

        if (!$.trim(name).length) {
            $edtName.css("border", "1px solid red")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could improve would be to get rid of the infinite loop. By calling `.submit()` from the `.submit()`, you've made a loop.

You can use the native `submit` in this case.

```
$("#frmCatAdd").submit(function() {
    var name = $("#edtName").val();

    if (name == "")
        $("#edtName").css("border", "1px solid red")
    else
        this.submit(); // call native submit method instead

    return false;
});
```

[Though @jAndy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648679/can-i-improve-my-validation/4648719#4648719) to get rid of the `else` and move the `return false` to the `if()` is better. Calling `submit` from `submit` is more important if you're running asynchronous code in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#frmCatAdd").submit(function() {
    $e = $(this).find("#edtName");
    if (!$.trim($e.val()).length) {
        $e.css("border", "1px solid red")
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer:

```
<form id=frmCatAdd>
<input id=edtName required type=text>
</form>
```

Of course, I should repeat the sentiment that you will need server-side validation as well.